# In MediaWiki, how to insert code block in bullet points?

Tags: html, mediawiki, markup

In MediaWiki, I do

```
* section
** item 1 blah blah
** item 2 blah blah 
 code block start
 ...
 code block start
** item 3 blah blah
```

This will result in item 3 being not correctly formatted -- there is a double bullet points in front of `item 3`.  Any ideas?

Update: The said issue only show up when there are two levels.

Comment: This seems like an end-user question and not a developer one. Not sure it really belongs here.

Comment: [Formatting MediaWiki lists](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Lists)

Comment: See answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85999/46980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with HTML:

```
<ol>
<li>option 1</li>
<li>option 2</li>
</ol>
 code here
<ol start="3">
  <li>option 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Works but not perfect.  So MediaWiki markup cannot handle this case?

Comment: No, it can't -- it's due to the way that the list items are formatted in CSS, unfortunately. When you have a nested list, there is no way (in CSS) to distinguish between a list where the first item is another list, or where there is some text and then another list.